# Pandas Timeseries plotting

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a Pandas timeseries object with dates and corresponding values. But, when I try to plot it, the plot is a L-shape plot (the dates and values are automatically arranged in such a way that the highest value comes first...).

This is what  did to generate the plot:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\data\test1.csv') # two-column dataframe
data_list = df['values'].tolist()
dates_list = df['date'].tolist()
df_ts = pd.Series(data_list, index=dates_list)
df_ts.plot()
```

I am not sure where I am making a mistake. I am reading in a csv file, converting to a timeseries obj and plotting it. Any suggestions is very much appreciated.

Thanks!
PD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't bother creating the unnecessary intermediate data structures, just organize your `DataFrame` better.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date) #make sure you're actually dealing with timestamps.
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.sort(inplace=True)
df.plot()
```

Comment: The data is still in a 'data frame' format. To compute timeseries anomalies, I think I will need to convert this data frame to a proper timeseries format and then work on it. Learning...now..

Comment: one thing is that each `DataFrame` column is actually a `Series`. the only thing that makes a `Series` a "timeseries" is its index, really. so by setting dates as the index, you actually do have a timeseries, so to speak.